# Panasonic VCR ND-SV350

Tags: electrical

I need help on the Panasonic NV-Sd 350 There is a circuit board next to the servo motor, and there are two Black wires with a Small Brown connector that goes on the Ereaser head.
Now need to confirm if That is the right place to re-solder them.
please see the attch.

Comment: take the VCR to a repair shop ... they can probably confirm if it is the right place ... you didn't ask a question, so I made an assumption that it is `who can confirm the location?`